How to enable macro on Excel sheet from OneDrive
I have created an Excel sheet. That has a lot of macros running.
I want to share the file on OneDrive with my colleagues. So all of us can work on same file.
Now, once they open the file from their OneDrive shared folder in their computer. It blocks the macros as security risk. I want these macros to work on all users who have access to the file in OneDrive.
I have tried adding the trusted locations from macros security. But it isn't accepting the URL as secure/valid according to my MS Office security settings. I am not able to find any solution for the problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Make sure in trusted locations and trusted documents to select to use network locations.
If anything in macro settings select "Enable VBA macros"
